# is it possible to find out how much of the db data is older than some N years in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two database in SQL Server. I wanted to find out the data older than (let say 3) years.

I know the database creation date, currently I have around 550 GB (both the database) of data spanned for 7 years, I wanted to know 'how much of the DB data (out of total 550 GB)is older than 3 years OR (5 years)'?

I was going through this link but couldn't get the expected data.

[SQL SERVER – Query to find number Rows, Columns, ByteSize for each table in the current database – Find Biggest Table in Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/10/sql-server-query-to-find-number-rows-columns-bytesize-for-each-table-in-the-current-database-find-biggest-table-in-database/)

One of the solution coming in my mind right now is to find out the total number of rows accounted for 7 years (easily get this number), total number of rows accounted for 5 years (starting from the date creation) (don't know how to get this number).

then for row_count_7_years accounts for 550 GB of data , what will be the row_count_5_years? i will get the approx data.

Please Help

Comment: You must have some kind of a `Date` or `DateTime` column in your tables in order to be able to tell how old the data is.

Comment: Or timespan datatype column

Answer (score 2):

For such purposes you should keep some datetime field as marc mentioned. I suppose you don't have it.

In you suggested solution you can get the whole count of rows from your table (for 7 years i suppose), but you wouldn't be able to get the rows for 5 years, because there is no date.

You can get the whole number of records for 7 years and divide them on the number of years, and ONLY IN CASE you have your database avarage fulfill, you can make query for top (numberOFRows in one year)*5 and order them by row_number(). The result - the rows, you should delete. But I wouldn't recommend you to use this solution.

I would recommend you to alter your tables and add the datetime columns for each of them. Before that you should make the backup for the whole date and copy it somewhere. After 3 years you would be able to make your clean up.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above u shud have a date column , however if you dont , depending on the realtionships in your tables u might be able to estimate the number of rows looking up realtionships with some other table that has the datetime column  , else if you have a backup ( unlikely but still) you can restore that to identify the delta